# jQuery UI Dialog hiding scroll bars

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

Scrolling becomes disabled when opening a jQuery UI dialog, even when it's open as non Modal.
It doesn't seem to be any option to control this behaviour.
How to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working solution myself.
Just after opening the dialog, add this piece of code:

```
$("html,body").css("scroll", "auto");
```

IMO, it has no sense at all to block scrolling when opening a non modal dialog. I'd say this is a bug or a missunderstanding of what a non-modal dialog is.